# Is re-pitching essential after cold crashing?

Tags: beer, yeast, conditioning, cold-crash

If I'm cold crashing a batch to clear it up, is it essential to re-pitch when bottling or will there be sufficient residual yeast for carbonation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very unlikely you will need to repitch.  even with cold conditioning, if you looked at the beer under a microscope you'd find there's still a lot of yeast in suspension.  I've lagered beers for months and still had enough yeast left for carbonation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - it depends. How long the beer was lagered? How flocculent strain?

Anyway, it's always good idea to add fresh yeast. Pick highly flocculent strain, like Saflager W34/70, 1/2tsp. is enough for 5gal. batch.